# Append newly query request ?page=2 to existing query ?q=python

Tags: python, django

I search `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?q=python` in my project home page which return results with multiple pages:

Here is my pagination sinppet

```
<ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
  {% for i in page.page_list %} 
    {% if i == page.number %}
    <li class="active">
        <a href="?page_number={{ i }}">{{ i }} </a>
    </li>
    {% else %}
    <li>
        <a href="?page_number={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a>
    </li>
    {% endif %} 
  {% endfor %} 
</ul>
```

When I click page 2 in the page, it issue request `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?page_number=2` rather than `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?q=python?page_number=2`

How append the `?page_number=2` to its existing query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `{% if %}` tag like this:

```
<a href="?page_number={{ i }}{% if request.GET.q %}&q={{ request.GET.q }}{% endif %}">{{ i }}</a>
```